# mongooseのアラートが消えない

Tags: javascript, mongodb

Facebookのクローンアプリを作ってます。mongoDBとローカルサーバーを接続してます。

ターミナルにアラートが出て、この警告のせいでこの後のPostmanを使ってpostリクエストを送る操作をする時にエラーが出てしまいます。

対処法を教えてください

[image: server.jsのファイル]
[image: ターミナルの警告文]

Comment: 起動時の警告と、Postmanで発生するエラーの関係性はどのように確認したのでしょうか? Postmanで発生するエラーを提示すると回答が得られやすくなるかもしれません。

Comment: コードやエラーメッセージはキャプチャ画像としてではなく、文字のまま質問に貼り付けてください。